# ui-router (Invalid params in state 'dash')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to setup a demo to showcase a problem I'm having with sibling components/states.

However running into this error:

[image]

No idea what would be wrong here, as this is how we have it in our current app:

```
params: {
  ticker: 'AAA'
}
```

---

https://plnkr.co/edit/zfmuZXp88cSbdOsibv3y?p=preview

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dash');

    var dash = {
      name: 'dash',
      url: '/dash?ticker',
      // params: {
      //   ticker: 'AAA'
      // },
      views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'partial-dash.html' },
        'tagsList@dash': { 
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: 'tagsController'
        },
        'tickersList@dash': { 
          templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
          controller: 'tickersController'
        }
      }
    };

    $stateProvider
      .state(dash);

});

routerApp.controller('tagsController', function($scope) {

    $scope.tags = [
      'tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3'  
    ];

    $onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tagsController');
    };

});

routerApp.controller('tickersController', function($scope, $state) {

    // $scope.changeScotchState = function() {
    //     $state.go('about', { scotch: true });
    // };

    $scope.tickers = [
      'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'
    ];

    $onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tickersController');
      console.log('$state.ticker', $state.params.ticker)
    };

});
```

Comment: Where is the `about` state? All I see is `dash`

Comment: @reptilicus hi, sorry there is no `about` state, basically there is just the parent dash state, and 2 child states: `tagsList` and `tickersList`. Updated my example and title to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I was using an older version of ui-router.

Switched to this and now the params var is supported:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js